# ELK docker GCP installation

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kibana

I have configured Kubernetes cluster on GCP and have reconfigured Docker based ELK.

The issue I'm facing is that I'm unable to use the kibana browser dashboard.

- Where to set the URL ?
- Where to get the external IP to access Kibana?

Comment: May be this will help, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/access.html

Comment: Hello Michel, welcome to Stack, in order to help you better, can you say if you are using GKE? Kubeadm on Compute Engine? or Minikube? If possible, add the results of `kubectl get svc`.

Comment: i am using GKE on that i have installed Docker (ELK)

Answer (score 0):

> The issue I'm facing is that I'm unable to use the kibana browser dashboard.
>   -   Where to set the URL ?

**You have to `kubectl expose` your kibana as `LoadBalancer` in order to gain external access.**

[LoadBalancer:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer)

> On cloud providers which support external load balancers, setting the `type` field to `LoadBalancer` provisions a load balancer for your Service.

The syntax is:

- kubectl expose deployment **kibana_deploy_name_here** --port=5601 --target-port=5601 --name=kibana-external-url --type=LoadBalancer

Here is my reproduction:

```
$ kubectl get deployment
NAME                     READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/kibana   1/1     1            1           14m

$ kubectl expose deploy kibana --port=5601 --target-port=5601 --name=kibana-external-url --type=LoadBalancer
service/kibana-external-url exposed
```

It will take a couple minutes in pending state:

```
$ kubectl get svc kibana-external-url
NAME                     TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kibana-external-url      LoadBalancer   10.0.1.54    <pending>     5601:31781/TCP   7s
```

And will automatically assign an External IP for you:

```
$ kubectl get svc kibana-external-url
NAME                  TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kibana-external-url   LoadBalancer   10.0.1.54    34.68.43.17   5601:31781/TCP   17m
```

> - Where to get the external IP to access Kibana?

Now just type the address assigned to your service + the port on your browser and you will be good to go.

[image]

*(Ignore the message, It's just because I haven't configured ES.)*

Let me know if you have any difficulties.

Comment: sorry unable to do the same i am having a kubernetes cluster can we connect on other modes for detailed discussion if you dont mind .

Comment: skype : moh143t_1

Comment: Can you please clarify what kind of issues you are still facing? As it might help other community members, I would rather stay in touch here. If you are willing to talk with somebody who can look into your issue deeply, you can maybe try: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs